# Is there an alternative way to my below code?

Tags: robotframework

I am looking for an alternative and smarter way to achieve the below action

```
***Keywords***

Insert Values
[Documentation]  Keyword is used to insert value
   ${Status1}               Run Keyword and Return Status       Wait Until Element is Visible     ${ONPDonorLocator}                1s
   ${Status2}               Run Keyword and Return Status       Wait Until Element is Visible     ${CustomerScoreLocator}           1s
   ${Status3}               Run Keyword and Return Status       Wait Until Element is Visible     ${ContractDurationLocator}        1s
   ${Status4}               Run Keyword and Return Status       Wait Until Element is Visible     ${OptionsInstalledLocator}        1s
   ${Status5}               Run Keyword and Return Status       Wait Until Element is Visible     ${OrderAddsDeletesLocator}        1s
   ${Status6}               Run Keyword and Return Status       Wait Until Element is Visible     ${SiteCategoryLocator}            1s
   Run Keyword If          '${Status1}'=='True'             Wait and Click    ${ONPDonor}               ${LocatorWaitTime}
   Run Keyword If          '${Status2}'=='True'             Wait and Click    ${CustomerScore}          ${LocatorWaitTime}
   Run Keyword If          '${Status3}'=='True'             Wait and Click    ${ContractDuration}       ${LocatorWaitTime}
   Run Keyword If          '${Status4}'=='True'             Wait and Click    ${OptionsInstalled}       ${LocatorWaitTime}
   Run Keyword If          '${Status5}'=='True'             Wait and Click    ${OrderAddsDeletes}       ${LocatorWaitTime}
   Run Keyword If          '${Status6}'=='True'             Wait and Click    ${SiteCategory}           ${LocatorWaitTime}
```

Expected:
Is it possible to click the locator that has `'${Status}'=='True'` instead of writing `Status1`, `Status2`, `Status3` and so on?
I do not want to write the way I have written above. Tomorrow if I have to check status of few more locators then the lines will keep on getting added.

Note: I am still learning, so any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using a loop and storing only the locators that are visible; then you loop over the stored ones, and click them:

```
${visible}=    Create List
FOR    ${locator}     IN     ${ONPDonorLocator}    ${CustomerScoreLocator}    # etc, the others
    ${Status}    Run Keyword and Return Status       Wait Until Element is Visible     ${locator}
    Run Keyword If    ${Status}    Append To List    ${visible}    ${locator}
END

FOR    ${locator}    IN    @{visible}
    Wait and Click    ${locator}
END
```

When you have more elements to wait for visibility and then click, you just add them in the first loop.

Comment: Hi @Todor,
I ran the above chunk of code and I got this error:

Comment: Configuring Promo :: New Promo Configuration from Campaign tool       | FAIL |
Variable '${Locator}' not found.

Comment: Check for typos; `${locator}` is the name of the temp variable used in the loops, and it's declared on lines 2 and 7 in the sample.

Comment: I just learned that Python version >= 3.6 is a pre-requisite for new For loop syntax. My system has version 2.7 which is why the above error. But anyways, my purpose has been met with the old for loop syntax. Thanks a ton!